# wordpress wp query posts & meta value

Tags: sql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a cpt "members".
In a post I can select multiple members (object) via ACF in the specific post.

Now I want say: Please give me all posts where a member (e.g. nr. 76) ist marked in the post.

I try the whole day, and have no idea.

It's possible if i change the acf field to one number to get the correct posts, but Its important that I can select multiple members.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
Finally got it :-)

$args = array(
'post_type'=>'post',
'numberposts'=> -1,
'meta_query' => array(
 array(
'key' => 'members',
 'value' => '76',  //example
'compare'=>'LIKE'
)
)             
);
```